# Example 6.3.2 Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

In Hartshorne's book on Algebraic geometry, the section on Weil Divisors has the following example:

[image]

How can I prove that this is true? The theorem above this example is about the divisor class group of a unique factorization domain, but I do not see how the proof given generalizes to Dedekind domains.

Any reference for a proof of this fact is also helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify your confusion a bit? Prop 6.2 applies to all Noetherian domains. A Dedekind domain is a Noetherian domain that is integrally closed and of dimension 1. So for Dedekind domains, 6.2 just reads $A$ is a UFD if and only if $\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Spec}(A)) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I do not see how this shows that the two groups are equal if it is not an UFD (i.e. the class group is not trivial).